# PassportJs authentication for action allowed to both ( guest and logged in user )

Tags: express, passport.js, bearer-token

I am new to expressJs and PassportJS trying to implement an API which return all basic details for a user i.e

```
{
    isUserLogin: true or false,
    allowedActions: [],
    applicationUrl: [],
    pageComponents: [],
    settings: []
}
```

So the problem that I am facing is if I implement passport.js than guest users are getting unauthorized. Below is my code.

router.js

```
authRoutes.get('/init', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: true }), authController.init);
```

controller.js

```
exports.init = (req, res) => {
    //here is my login to get params. Guest user not able to reach it.

    res.status(200).send(params);
};
```

I think it must be a simple setting at router level but unable to get proper document for this. I am stuck on this for more than 6 days. Any suggestions which could lead me in the right direction will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`passport-anonymous`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-anonymous) for.

Install with: `npm install passport-anonymous`

Then use the strategy

```js
const AnonymousStrategy = require('passport-anonymous').Strategy;

passport.use(new AnonymousStrategy());
```

Then on your route, pass array of authentication strategies instead of string:

```js
authRoutes.get('/init', passport.authenticate(['bearer', 'anonymous'], { session: true }), authController.init);
```

And on the controller, you can check whether the user is logged in by checking the `req.user` object. Keep in mind that you must put `anonymous` after the `bearer` in the array

```js
exports.init = (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
        console.log("Logged in");
    } else {
        console.log("Guest");
    }

    res.status(200).send(params);
};
```